# SwiftUI preference, transformPreference, onPreferenceChanged

Tags: swiftui, preferences

How to pass several preferences for given preference key?

```
 var body: some View {

        MyTabView {

            Page1()
                .preference(key: TabItemPreferenceKey.self, value: [TabItemPreference(tag: 0, item: AnyView(Text("Tab 1")) ) ] )


            Page2()
                .preference(key: TabItemPreferenceKey.self, value: [TabItemPreference(tag: 1, item: AnyView(Text("Tab 12")) ) ] )
```

Then in MyTabView I am trying to access this preferences but there is only first preference available

```
.onPreferenceChange(TabItemPreferenceKey.self) { preferences in
                preferences.forEach { p in
                    self.items.tabItems.append((tag: p.tag, tab: p.item))
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
.transformPreference( _, _)
```

to combine multiple preferences

Comment: Yes I know, I found the source of problem but it was related to displaying views.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimental debugging I've found the source of the problem. I've used `.preference(key:)` call on  PageX() views inside MyTabView, but this views were **conditionally displayed on screen!** So .preference(key:) registers this preference only for displayed views. 
I make a workaround to this issue using .hidden(). I only have concerns about performance as it would be better to display only needed page not add all pages at once and then hide them. But for now I do not know any other workaround.

Here is How I display this views to which I am attaching preferences:

```
var body: some View {
        ForEach(0..<childs.count, id: \.self) { i in
            Group {
                if i == self.model.selection {
                    self.childs[i]
                } else {
                    self.childs[i].hidden()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don’t change views here , change or filter the data range.

Comment: I am changing views as only one is visible at given time. If I display only one view and then preference() is not invoked on this views that are not attached to view hierarchy

Comment: Here the question is what info you record in the customized key? if they are not view or shown view related,those infos are supposed to save in data model.